# Countif returning value on itself?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a simple formula trying to count how many times the text in a cell is repeated within the column. I drag the formula down, hence the absolute references in the range.

This formula is returning a #VALUE error on most cells:

```
=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$67,E2)
```

I do not understand why, since at the very least `e2` would be equal to `e2`, so there should be at least 1 match!  I thought maybe because it was text, but I tried looking and everywhere I looked says that `countif` works with text.
Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data you're using?

Comment: I do not get any errors. Does you column contain errors themselves?

Comment: Had to shorten the steps to protect disclosing trade secrets, but:

     1. Advise the customer .
     2. Review current installation date.
     3. Clear the order and resubmit.  
     4. If customer wants to cancel, cancel order.

There are no special characters or anything in the text that was omitted.   Also, I used the CLEAN function on the data and tried on the cleaned data with the same results.

Comment: No errors Scott, just text.    Thank you to you and Carl for your help, btw.

Comment: Your explanation does not help us to see the problem.  Please find a small set of made up data that give you the same error and post that in your original post using edit.  The formula works for us and our made up data, so we cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the results.  To answer the question that Bruce asked, I unfortunately do not have the source.   I was given the Excel spreadsheet.   I do not know where the data came from and it is an old sheet, so I have nobody to ask where the data came from.   I suspect that Bruce is right, though.   Is there any way of knowing what characters are causing the issue or "clean up" the data?   I tried copying and pasting into Word, but all I see are carriage returns.  I can manually type in the same data with carriage returns and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are unable to duplicate the problem with generic data, and you cannot provide information needed to diagnose the problem due to confidentiality concerns.

Please see [this help article from Office](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/How-to-correct-a-VALUE-error-15e1b616-fbf2-4147-9c0b-0a11a20e409e) on diagnosing #VALUE errors in general

And [this help article from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/260415) regarding #VALUE errors on aggregate functions.

If your data references an external workbook you may wish to try a combination of `SUM()` and `IF()` instead on `COUNTIF()` like so:

`=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$67,E2)`

`=SUM(IF($E$2:$E$67=E2,1,0))`